# robotframework :IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u"headers={u'Authorization': u'authToken AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcw2MbHyyr8ikI7zByHH1yFK7rVS-YYPzRQ

Tags: robotframework

Hi I am getting mentioned error message while executing below robotframwork script,

```
Get AuthToken
    ${jsontemplate}=        Get File            ${TEMPLATE LOCATION}/ts_Authtoken.json
    ${jsoncontent}=         Replace Variables   ${jsontemplate}
    ${rc}       ${response}=        Do Post     ${AUTHTOKEN}            ${jsontemplate}
    Log     ${rc}
    Log     ${response}
    Should Be Equal     ${rc}       ${200}
    ${Substring} =      Get Substring       ${response}     91      210
    Log     ${Substring}
    ${Substring1} =     Get Substring       ${Substring}        1       10
    Log     ${Substring1}
    ${Substring2} =     Get Substring       ${Substring}        13      119
    Log     ${Substring2}
    ${Substring3}=          catenate        ${Substring1}       ${Substring2}   
    Log             ${Substring3}
    ${headers}=    Create Dictionary    Authorization    ${Substring3}
    Log    ${headers}

    ${rc1}      ${result} =    Do Post    ${CREATEUP}    ${jsontemplate1}    headers=${headers}
    Log     ${rc1}
    Log     ${result}
```

Comment: What is your question? What arguments does "Do Post" expect? The error message implies it thinks the third argument is a file.  Can you show the definition of the keyword "Do post" since it's not a standard keyword?

Comment: Here I am trying to post the webservice request by providing body,which is present in ${jsontemplate1}.But the webservice i am trying, needed authorization header to be passed which will be having authToken *****

Comment: None of that is relevant at the moment. The problem isn't with the service, the problem is that the _keyword_ seems to be expecting a filename and you're giving it something else. What does the definition of "Do Post" look like?

Comment: Now getting below error,


IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: u"headers={u'Content-Type': u'application/json', u'Authorization': u'authToken AQIC5wM2LY4SfczVFf

Is this because of extra characters "u'" in the value I am passing?if so what could be the solution to remove them.Would be great help to solve this issue.

Comment: No, the problem still seems to be that your keyword needs a filename and you're giving it a dictionary.

Comment: Hi Bryan..Thanks a for the quick reply...

I need to pass authorization ..dont knwo how to pass that through file..Any help would be appriciated..

Comment: You're asking us how to call a custom keyword, without showing us how that keyword is defined. We can't help without knowing what "Do Post" requires as arguments. You need to show us how "Do post" is defined since that is not a standard robot keyword.

Comment: Authorization as a header during post request along with content-type

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error message of the form "No such file or directory: *(something that doesn't look like a filename)*", that usually means that the keyword you are calling is expecting a filename, and you're giving it something else.

Based on what little information has been provided, my guess is that "Do Post" requires a filename as its third parameter but you are passing a string that begins with "headers={..."